# HH:MM:SS time data coming wrongly in Power Bi from Excel

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to load excel data into power Bi and in that excel, one column is reported as HH:MM:SS timing but when I load the same into Power Bi, I am getting completely different values such as date, time and AM/PM.

Kindly help me in this.

---

I tried uploading the data and in that column name Avg Talk Duration which is reported in HH:MM:SS is gettinng shown as Date, Time and AM/PM. Attaching all snaps.

[Table in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNgbf.png)

[Table view in Power Bi report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXFgG.png)

[Table in Power Query Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPVMq.png)

Nothing is working in Table View mode when I change Column Tools> Format because practically there is no data in that mode.